# How to match one character in MySQL in place of %?

Tags: mysql

In the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y LIKE "%s";
```

the `%` will match any characters before an `s`. The `%` can be `x`, `xx`, `xrf`, etc.

Is there any symbol that will only match one character, like:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y LIKE "?s"
```

where `?` will match only one character like `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.?

Comment: Any word which has 'a' appearing only once?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You want to use an underscore (`_`) character. See the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

Answer (score 20):

`_` will match exactly one character :

```
select * from X where Y like "_s"
```

Answer (score 5):

An easy way you can do it if you know the domain of characters to match:

```
select * from X where Y like '[a-z]s'
```

or like this

```
select * from X where Y like '[a-zA-Z0-9]s'
```

alternatively you could use the _ (underscore) syntax like follows:

```
select * from X where Y like '_s'
```

Comment: Using `[a-z]` doesn't seem to work with `LIKE`, I suppose it only work for `REGEXP`

Comment: Yes, you have to use rlike not like. Like works with _ and %.

Comment: Note that the question is about MySQL but probably this answer is about SQL server