# How do i check and print a name with a matching prefixed and suffixed letters?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I want to print the Names of which the letter `e` has 3 prefix letters

Input:

```
Mikesanch, Mantis, Jamesh
```

Output

```
Mikesach, Jamesh
```

Input

```
Letter e has 3 three prefix Letters and 2 suffix letters
```

Output

```
Jamesh
```

Comment: MySQL uses an underscore (`_`) as a single-character wildcard for the `LIKE` operator. You can use one underscore for each letter in the prefix and suffix. Related: [How to match one character in MySQL in place of %?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5247763/5209322)

Comment: improved formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a bit more details on your database structure. Assuming you have a TABLE "persons" with the COLUMN "name", you can do something like:

```
SELECT name 
FROM persons
WHERE name LIKE '___e%';
```

It will check if the 3rd letter of the name is a 'e' and display only matching answers.